# Internal Server Error on heroku sails deploy

Tags: node.js, heroku, sails.js, internal-server-error, heroku-postgres

I am trying to deploy my sails.js app to heroku. I have deployed it but whenever I open a page which requires data from DB it says `Internal Server Error`. I think it might be a problem with my DB connection. I have created a postgresql DB on heroku and have set the connections in connections.js. Connection.js code is

```
module.exports.connections = {
     'mysql-adapter': {
         module: 'sails-mysql',
         url: "postgres://username:pass@ec2-107-22-249-214.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dcebipdspqn7rn",
         port: 5432,
         schema:true
     }
};
```

I have been searching on the net for 2 days and have tried many tweaks but none has worked for me. Kindly tell me how to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

I checked the logs and it says

```
←[33m2015-02-25T14:20:38.793179+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  Could not render view "displayroute/viewRoute".  Tried locating view file @ "/app/views/displayroute/view
Route". Layout configured as "layout", so tried using layout @ "/app/views/layout")
```

However, the view is rendered correctly on localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your connection definition looks completely wrong and schema key should be in the models config object (either in config/models.js or in the api/models/YourModelDefinition.js or on the sails.config.models object).

I would reference the examples in connections.js found here
https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/anatomy/myApp/config/connections.js.md

Remember that if you are using postgres then you need to install the adapter

```
npm install sails-postgresql
```

Comment: I followed your link. I am still getting `Internal Server Error`. And the same message on log

Comment: Are you using postgres locally and does it work locally. Also are those connection details important? You need to be careful with the username password being posted online.

Comment: I have deleted the above comment because of user pass. And yes postgresql works locally all right

Comment: are you sure it is working locally with postgres? Have you checked your local db?, I ask because your original code was very wrong and I wonder if your not using the default memory db or something?